# Bootstrap 3 Modal with Image and scroll bars

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I have modal dialog which has one image of width `1500px`. I want the image be always of that size and in case of smaller screen sizes I want to show the modal with scroll bars, i.e. it should stay adaptive but scrolls must appear. So the user can see the whole image by scrolling the modal body.

My modal:

```
Modal::begin([
        'header' => Yii::t('app', ''),
        'id' => 'mapModalId',
        'class' =>'modal',           
    ]);

    echo $this->render('/site/map');

    Modal::end();
```

/site/map.php

```
 <img src="<?=Yii::getAlias('@web')."/images/map.png"?>" alt="">
```

I'd appreciate if you could provide demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two key pieces to this and it happens entirely in CSS.

1. Set the width and height of the image + override the max-width: 100% css rule that you most likely have applied to all images. This ensures the image will display at the size you have chosen (1500px)
2. Set the modal-body (or whatever container is holding the image) to have a property of "overflow: scroll". This makes it so the image doesn't overflow into outerspace and instead adds a scroll bar to the image container.

Here is a codepen using a default BS3 modal w/ an image with dimensions of 1500x500 placed in the modal-body.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXZQzx

The CSS you would need is as follows. Of course, change the class of modal-body to whatever container you have your image in.

```
.modal-body {
  overflow: scroll;
}
/* overrides the max-width: 100% that you may have on all images */
.modal-body img {
  max-width: auto;
}
```